# Question regarding isomorphisms formed by deleting various edges in a plane triangulation...

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a plane triangulation $T$ with $m$ edges numbered $1, 2, … , m$. Form the near-triangulation $G_k$ by deleting the edge $e_k$ in $T$. Suppose the $m$ near-triangulations $G_k$ for $k = 1, 2, … , m$ are isomorphic. What does that tell us about the structure of $T$?  In particular, anything about regularity or symmetry of $T$?